# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$$

**My attempt**: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^3}\cdot x$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \sin^3(x)\cdot \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x^3}$$

Is this the right path? If so, what should I do next?

Comment: As long as you don't do something silly like claiming that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin \frac 1x}{\frac1x}$ should be $1$, you are yet to do anything formally wrong. You have not tapped into the right idea either, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice, $\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\in [-1,1] \ \ \ \forall \ \ x\in \mathbb R$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}   \underbrace{\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}}_{\to 1}\cdot \underbrace{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}_{-1\le\large \boxed{} \le 1}\cdot \underbrace{x}_{\to 0}$$
$$=0$$

Comment: $\sin(1/x) \in [-1,1]$ not $\sin(1/x) \to [-1,1]$.

Comment: OK, $\sin \theta$ fluctuates between $-1$ & $+1$ (i.e. bounded function). So generally you can say that $\sin(\text{any real})\in[-1,1]$

Comment: Sure, but your arrow notation in the underbracing is still wrong. $\sin(1/x) \not\to [-1,1]$. Or at the very least you are using very informal notation that I would not have fully accepted when I taught calculus.

Comment: Yes, that is my own notation which just means $sin(1/x)$ lies in $[-1,1]$. But you can suggest proper notation if any.

Comment: I already did: $\sin(1/x) \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: I have removed that notation. I just showed it by interval. Is that OK?

Comment: Sure. Your $x$ is rendering as a square for me, but that might just be a browser issue.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

We use the fact that
$$|\sin(x)|\le |x|$$ and
$$|\sin(\frac 1x)|\le 1$$ to get

$$|\frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac 1x)}{x^2}|\le |x|$$

thus

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(\frac 1x)}{x^2}=0$$